# Highcharts Won't load from php json, but it could load from data.json file

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I tried to make a highchart from JSON data. I make a php file that generating the json and insert the address to the getJSON() like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {...
```

and it wont work, so i decided to put the php inside the highcharts file like this.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

$resu = array();
$measurement = $_POST["choosenmeasurement"];

for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["choosenbusid"]); $i++)
{
$busid = $_POST["choosenbusid"][$i];
$clusid = $_POST["choosenclusterid"][$i];

$fieldname = ''.$measurement.'_BUSID_'.$busid.'_CLUSTERID_'.$clusid;

$sql= "SELECT unix_timestamp, $measurement as $fieldname FROM `get` WHERE bus_id = $busid and cluster_id = $clusid";
$sth = $mysqli->query($sql);

$out = array();
$out['name'] = $fieldname;
while ($rr = $sth->fetch_assoc()) {
$out['data'][] = $rr[$fieldname];

}
array_push($resu,$out);

}
$jsonresult = json_encode($resu);



?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(<?php $jsonresult>, function(json) {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'testchart',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: json
        });
        });

    });

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and it won't load either and i tried many ways with that method like put $jsonresult into javascript variable, echoing the json, print the json, print/echo into the getJSON() and still wont work eventhough if i echo the json to a blank space it'll print a json structure that i want.

BUT

if i put the JSON file into getJSON() like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("test.json", function(json)
```

it will works. but i would not copy paste the json that generated into the json file everytime i would load the charts.

i just wondering why. Any help?

Comment: The first guess is that generated JSON isn't proper. I suggest to validate your JSON generated on a server (you can use this: http://jsonlint.com/). Anyway, what errors do you have in JavaScript console?

Comment: One thing, can you run echo the $jsonresult to see it's format and iclude it in your post please.

Comment: i have tried. and it's a valod json

Comment: [{"name":"Hz_BUSID_1_CLUSTERID_1","data":["49.5798","49.58","49.58","49.58","49.58","49.58","49.58"]},{"name":"Hz_BUSID_2_CLUSTERID_1","data":["49.5798","49.58","49.58","49.58","49.58","49.58","49.58"]},{"name":"Hz_BUSID_1_CLUSTERID_2","data":["48.4136","48.4137","48.4137","48.4137","48.4137","48.4137","48.4138"]},{"name":"Hz_BUSID_6_CLUSTERID_1","data":["49.5798","49.58","49.58","49.58","49.58","49.58","49.58"]}]

Comment: You values are strings, should be numbers.

Comment: As Pawel says, the Json is wrong. You should only have numbers

Comment: should i use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ?

Comment: No, the way you prepare data before transforming it is incorrect. I comented lower how to do it.

Comment: But the flag JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK should be used, because it allows to return INTs instead of strings.

Comment: this thing's has solved about several weeks ago. i have echo the result directly to to the highcharts series like this `series = <?php echo $result ?>` and it works. thanks btw guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same so in javascript part you have to inclide this:

```
var json = "<?php echo $pepito; ?>";
datar = JSON.parse(json);
```

This way you have the data from php in javascript

Also it's important to pass data in array and time in timestamp format multiplied by 1000. for example:

```
    $timestamp=strtotime($fila[0].$fila[1])*1000;
    //echo "\n".$timestamp;
$hola[0][]=array(   $timestamp, (float)$fila[2]);//RGD
$hola[1][]=array(   $timestamp, (float)$fila[3]);//RGA
```

You have to include the libraries before your script, not sure it's important but you should change it just in case:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

If you have any other quiestion or you need more info let me know.

Comment: do you mean like this:   var json = "<?php echo $jsonresult; ?>";
 data = JSON.parse(json);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON(data, function(json)   i have tried, but it won't work either my friend.

Comment: to receive the data from your php part you have to invoce it, for that use     var json = "<?php echo $jsonresult ; ?>";
        datar = JSON.parse(json);

Comment: Yes, use that instead of:       $.getJSON(<?php $jsonresult>
JSON.parse translates data into a formay for javascript

Comment: i have tried your solution to use JSON.parse(); but it still wont work.

Comment: Can you show me the output of your: $jsonresult, simply write:
    echo $jsonresult;

Comment: i put it on comment above.

Comment: In your while write: 

$out[0][] = array($rr[0],$rr[1])

And change while to:

while($rr = $sth->fetch_row())

Comment: while ($rr = $sth->fetch_row()) {
  $out[0][] = array($rr[0],$rr[1]);
 }

Comment: well. it generates a little different JSON. would it affecting how i code the Highcharts?

Comment: It's the format which Highchart accepts, if after this it still doesn't work, let me know and i'll post my whole code.